# Как убрать рамку у canvas при использовании tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

```
canvas = Canvas(top, width=1000, height=600, bg = "lightblue", cursor = "circle")
```

`bd` или `borderwidth`, согласно документации, должен работать, но от вставки в строку параметра ничего не меняется вообще (ни в большую ни в меньшую сторону) и ошибку не выдает. Как убрать рамку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Этот ответ смотрели? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310489/how-do-i-remove-the-light-grey-border-around-my-canvas-widget

Comment: @Baterson помогло, хотя не ответило на вопрос, почему изменение bd не оказывает влияния. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
canvas_1 = Canvas(root, width=200, height=200, bg='red', highlightthickness=0)
canvas_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]